# How to use PactJS with Cypress?

Tags: cypress, pact

I want to befriend [PactJS](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-js) and [Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/).

Here's the thing, since cypress integration tests run inside of browser, node environment is not available in it, thus I can't use [Pact](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-js#consumer-side-testing) objects anywhere in tests.

### Via Cypress task

Nevertheless I can implement cypress [task](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task.html#Syntax), and move all cypress related code to this task and make all communication via other tasks. This ways the flow becomes too complicated, it requires supporting the lifecycle of Pact object in the task, and duplicate all messages. Like this:

**cypress/plugins/index.js**:

```js
const {Pact} = require("@pact-foundation/pact")
  module.exports = (on) => {
  on("task", {
    createPactServer() {
      return new Pact({
        consumer: "TodoApp",
        provider: "TodoService",
        port: 8501,
        // log: path.resolve(process.cwd(), "logs", "pact.log"),
        // dir: path.resolve(process.cwd(), "pacts"),
        logLevel: "info",
      })
    }
  })
}
```

**cypress/integration/test.js**:

```js
describe("Login page", (): void => {
  it("should log in", (): void => {
    let a = cy.task('createPactServer', );
    // do rest
    // manage verify
    // handle errors from verify
    //  shutdown pact server
    // handle all other lifecycle events.
  });
});
```

I would like to avoid that way!!

### Via cypress route

Also cypress comes with [route](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route.html#Syntax) that allows to mock the network and stub the responses. I wonder if there's any way to mix those, so I would not even to listen a port with Pact server at all. I didn't find any way thought I didn't investigate it for too long. There's also pact-web that seems to me only the mock part w/o http server, but there's no doc on integration it with API. Also I found out that pact uses ruby files, which probably makes it impossible to use w/o http server in non-node env.

I wonder if anyway tried to couple those together and what would be the preferred way.

Comment: This is so timely - we've been discussing how we may be able to make all of this work together but none of the core maintainers have a good grasp on Cypress. Would you care to join our slack channel so we can discuss there? I'm not sure we can fully resolve this via SO. slack.pact.io - you can DM me and we can go from there.

Comment: I would also like to get updated on this we want our integration, contract and e2e tests together (heck, even unit test with cypress' jest plug-in).

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE (2022):**

There are now two improvements:

1. Shared test fixtures described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68492932/1008568 (this is how we use Pact + Cypress together at Pactflow, in the standard "consumer driven" Pact mode)
2. We have created a [Cypress Pact Adapter](https://github.com/pactflow/pact-cypress-adapter/). This is primarily intended for use with Pactflow's [bi-directional contract testing](https://docs.pactflow.io/docs/bi-directional-contract-testing/) feature, but there are some feature requests/PR that are looking at adding Matcher and Provider States support that could make it more suitable to the consumer-driven model.

---

I've just created a [demonstration](https://github.com/pactflow/example-consumer-cypress) application combining the two together. I've found the experience to be [quite good](https://pactflow.io/blog/cypress-pact-front-end-testing-with-confidence/). What it does:

1. The Pact plugin will dynamically create a `server` and corresponding `route` for each registered interaction (so they are fast)
2. It will setup default route handlers to catch any requests that weren't explicitly configured (to avoid missing real requests and therefore losing confidence)
3. The use of route aliases and `cy.wait` is still possible, so the dev experience is retained as if you weren't using Pact

I plan on extracting this into a separate cypress plugin.

Below is what the example test code looks like to somebody using the plugin:

**Example**

```js
import { Matchers } from "@pact-foundation/pact-web";
const { like, eachLike } = Matchers;

let server;

const expectedProduct = {
  id: "10",
  type: "CREDIT_CARD",
  name: "28 Degrees",
};

describe("Product page", () => {
  describe("when products exist", () => {
    before(() => {
      cy.mockServer({
        consumer: "example-cypress-consumer",
        provider: "example-provider",
      }).then(opts => {
        server = opts
      })
    });

    it("can navigate to an individual product", () => {
      cy.addMockRoute({
        server,
        as: 'products',
        state: "products exist",
        uponReceiving: "a request to all products",
        withRequest: {
          method: "GET",
          path: "/products",
        },
        willRespondWith: {
          status: 200,
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          },
          body: eachLike(expectedProduct),
        },
      });
      cy.addMockRoute({
        server,
        as: 'product',
        state: "a product with ID 10 exists",
        uponReceiving: "a request to get a product",
        withRequest: {
          method: "GET",
          path: "/product/10",
        },
        willRespondWith: {
          status: 200,
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          },
          body: like(expectedProduct),
        },
      });

      // Navigate to products listing page
      cy.visit("http://localhost:3000");
      cy.wait("@products");

      // Filter to the product we want
      cy.get("#input-product-search").type("28 degrees");

      // Navigate to individual product
      cy.contains("See more!").click();
      cy.wait("@product");

      // ... Assert something about product page
    });
  });
});
```

**Final Thoughts**

I still think where possible it makes sense to do this form of testing at the right layer where you can target the API client more directly. But this approach would solve a number of problems (broader audience, really nice dev experience and retrofitting usecases) and if used appropriate could be a good path for many.

Here is a video https://youtu.be/jTuuYMFJBBQ that shows:

1. First run navigates to `/` which calls out to an Product listing API `/products`
2. Second run extends the test to click through to a product page which needs to hit `/products/:id`. The test fails, because the interaction hasn’t been configured in Cypress or Pact
3. Add the `product/:id` interaction in and voila!

Answer (score -3):

Why do you want to couple cypress and pact? I have been used both before and I think that is better to avoid that dependency.

By one hand, You can use cypress for E2E tests because Cypress is for anything that runs in a browser. It means that you do not need to refer directly to services, controllers, etc. 
By the other hand, you can use Pact JS (with mocha) for contract tests. As you should know, Pact follows a consumer driven contract approach. It means that you have to create the pact file from the consumer, for that you have to do unit tests against controllers (or the http calls method) and you can’t do that with cypress.

Comment: The Pact mock server doesn't care if it is being called by Cypress controlling the app or a Jest unit test. It seems like an obvious combination to me.